# My rotation in second loop cannot enter the scale function in animation webgl

Tags: javascript, html, animation, webgl

I am pretty new to webgl. I am given an assignment to do a loop animation for rotation then scaling, means it will always rotate then scale. However, the first loop is okay but the second loop the rotation( ) cannot escape the loop and enter the scale function like in the first loop. It will just keep rotating there with strange behaviour. I have set value step as the control variable for which function to run.

I show my code to my professor and he has no clue, and I spend more than 2 days on this single problem. Hope someone else can enlighten me, any help is very appreciated. My js code is long but i comment out the section to make it more readable.

The COMMON file is provided by lecturer

**PROBLEM SOLVED**
**the problem lies in the else if (scaleFactor<=1) of function scaletion //1 , if I put any value smaller than 1 it works, any value >= 1 it works strange, and I have no idea ~**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
    <title>3D Sierpinski Gasket</title>

</head>   

<body>
    <div class="container">

            Animation Speed..........                      
        <input type="range" min="1" max="5" value="3" steps = "1" class="slider" id="animSpeed" onmouseup="updateAnimSpeed()">
        <label class = "label" id= "aSpeedLabel">3</label><br>

        Rotation Axis...............
        <input type="range" min="1" max="2" steps="1" value="1" class="slider" id="rotationAxis" onmouseup="updateAxis()">
        <p class = "label" id= "rAxisLabel">Axis Z</p><br>

        Number of Subdivision
        <input type="range" min="1" max="6" steps="1" value="4" class="slider" id="subDivision" onmouseup="updateDivision()">
        <p class = "label" id= "subLabel">4</p><br>


        <button type= "button" class= "animButton" id= "animButton" onclick="stopAnimate()">StopAnimate</button>  
        <button type= "button" class= "animButton" id= "animButton" onclick="animation()">Animate</button>


    </div>

    <div class= "gasket">
        <script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
            attribute vec4 vPosition;

            attribute vec4 vColor;
            varying vec4 color;

            varying vec2 v_texcoord;
            attribute vec2 a_texcoord;

            uniform mat4 initScale;

            uniform mat4 translation;
            uniform mat4 rotationX;
            uniform mat4 rotationY;
            uniform mat4 rotationZ;
            uniform mat4 scaling;

            void main()
            {
                gl_Position = vPosition * initScale * rotationX * rotationY * rotationZ * translation * scaling;

                color = vColor;
            }
        </script>

        <script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
            precision mediump float;
            varying vec4 color;

            void main()
            {
                gl_FragColor = color;
            }
        </script>

        <script id="fragment-shader2" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
            precision mediump float;
            uniform sampler2D u_texture;
            varying vec2 v_texcoord; 

            void main()
            {
                gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord);
            }
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="Common/webgl-utils.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Common/initShaders.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Common/MV.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="gasket4.js"></script>

       <canvas id="gl-canvas" width="680" height="680" class="canvas">
            Oops ... your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas element
        </canvas>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
var canvas;
var gl;
var program;

var points = [];                                    //all points goes here
var colors = [];                                    //all color data goes here
var vertices = [                                    //positions of the 4 inital corner vertices, will be subdivided
    vec3(  0.0000,  0.0000, -1.0000 ),
    vec3(  0.0000,  0.9428,  0.3333 ),
    vec3( -0.8165, -0.4714,  0.3333 ),
    vec3(  0.8165, -0.4714,  0.3333 )
];



var subDivisionCount = 6;                           //subdivision count
var aspectRatio = 1.5;                              //canvas aspect ratio
                                 //determines if animation is being played, for cancellation purposes

var id;
var step = 0;                                  //animation sequence
var nextSeq = false;                                //determine whether to go for next sequence

var radians = 0.0;                                  //rotation angle
var scaleFactor = 1.0;                              //scale size
var posX = 0.0, posY = 0.0, posZ = 0.0;             //position, -1.0 -> 1.0 clipped space

var rotationSpeed = 0.02, translationSpeed = 0.01, scaleSpeed = 0.01;   //default animation speed
var animSpeedValue, axisToRotate;
var color1Value, color2Value, color3Value, color4Value, fracStyle;
var rotate2=false, rotate=true;

var animSpeed, aSpeedLabel, rotationAxis, rAxisLabel, subDivision, subLabel;                 //html controllers
var color1, color2, color3, color4, useTexture, animButton, fractalStyle, fractalLabel;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////variable//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

window.onload = function init()                                                               //Main function
{

    setUpWegGL();                                                                             //set up web gl
    getAllController();                                                                       //reference to html controllers

    divideTetra( vertices[0], vertices[1], vertices[2], vertices[3], subDivisionCount);       //forms the gasket       

    configGL();                                                                               //configure wel gl settings     

    setUpVertexShader();
    setUpFragmentShader();                                                                    //create buffer and link to shader program

    initScale(0.7/aspectRatio,0.7,0.7);                                                       //scale down to a smaller size    
    scaling(1,1,1);                                                                           //transformation
    rotationX(0.0);
    rotationY(0.0); 
    rotationZ(0.0);         
    translation(0.0,0.0,0.0);
    animation();  


                                                                              //draw out the object
};  

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////animation start here//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function animation()
{





   if (step==0)
   rotation();
   else if(step==1)
    scaletion();


     id=window.requestAnimFrame( animation );


        render();



}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////animation function here//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function rotation(){

     radians-=rotationSpeed*animSpeedValue;  

         if(radians<-3.142)
         { rotationSpeed=-rotationSpeed

         }

         else if (radians>=0)
         {
            step++;                                       // step ++ to go to scale function , the problem is here in second loop, it cannot escape
            rotationSpeed=-rotationSpeed

            radians=0.0;


         }


 rotationZ(radians);

}
function translate(){

    posX+=translationSpeed*animSpeedValue;
    if(posX>0.5)
    translationSpeed=-translationSpeed;
    else if(posX<-0.5)
    translationSpeed=-translationSpeed;

    translation(posX,posX,posX);
     }

function scaletion(){

        scaleFactor+=scaleSpeed*animSpeedValue;

        if(scaleFactor>2)
    scaleSpeed=-scaleSpeed;

        else if (scaleFactor<1)
        {
            scaleFactor=1.0;
            step--;                                     // step -- to go back to rotation






        }
        scaling(scaleFactor,scaleFactor,scaleFactor);




}
var requestAnimFrame =  window.requestAnimationFrame || 
            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||  
            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
            window.oRequestAnimationFrame || 
            window.msRequestAnimationFrame ;


     function stopAnimate()
      {cancelAnimationFrame( id );
      }


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////animation fucntion here/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


function getAllController()
{
    animSpeed   = document.getElementById("animSpeed");
    aSpeedLabel = document.getElementById("aSpeedLabel");
    rotationAxis= document.getElementById("rotationAxis");
    rAxisLabel  = document.getElementById("rAxisLabel"); 
    subDivision = document.getElementById("subDivision"); 
    subLabel    = document.getElementById("subLabel"); 
    animButton  = document.getElementById("animButton");
    color1      = document.getElementById("color1"); 
    color2      = document.getElementById("color2");  
    color3      = document.getElementById("color3");  
    color4      = document.getElementById("color4");  

    animSpeedValue = animSpeed.value; 
    subDivisionCount = subDivision.value;
    axisToRotate = rotationAxis.value;
    color1Value = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    color2Value = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    color3Value = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    color4Value = vec3(0.0, 0.2, 0.2);
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function render()
{
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, points.length);
}



function setUpWegGL()
{
    canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );
    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );

    if ( !gl ) 
    alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); 
    else 
    aspectRatio = canvas.width/canvas.height;
}

function configGL()
{
    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    gl.clearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );

    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST); //hidden surface removal


    program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );

    gl.useProgram(program);
}

function setUpVertexShader()
{
    var vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(points), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );           //get vertex shader from html file
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);        
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition ); 
}

function setUpFragmentShader()
{
    var cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();                                        //allocate empty memory sapce
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer );                              //connect the memory space to gl
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW );      //add data to the connected memory space

    var vColor = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vColor" );                 //get frag shader from html file
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vColor, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vColor );  


}
/////////////////////////// triangle ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function triangle( a, b, c, color )
{
    var baseColors =                        //Change color here
    [
        color1Value,
        color2Value,
        color3Value,
        color4Value
    ];

    colors.push( baseColors[color] );
    points.push( a );
    colors.push( baseColors[color] );
    points.push( b );
    colors.push( baseColors[color] );
    points.push( c );
}

function tetra( a, b, c, d )
{
    triangle( a, c, b, 0 );     // tetrahedron with each side using a different color
    triangle( a, c, d, 1 );
    triangle( a, b, d, 2 );
    triangle( b, c, d, 3 );
}

function divideTetra( a, b, c, d, count )
{
    if ( count === 0 ) {                    //default state for recursion
        tetra( a, b, c, d );
    }

    else                                   
    {                                       // find midpoints of sides
        var ab = mix( a, b, 0.5 );          // divide four smaller tetrahedra , data type = array
        var ac = mix( a, c, 0.5 );
        var ad = mix( a, d, 0.5 );
        var bc = mix( b, c, 0.5 );
        var bd = mix( b, d, 0.5 );
        var cd = mix( c, d, 0.5 );

        --count;

        divideTetra(  a, ab, ac, ad, count );         //for all 4 faces of the tetrahedron
        divideTetra( ab,  b, bc, bd, count );
        divideTetra( ac, bc,  c, cd, count );
        divideTetra( ad, bd, cd,  d, count );
    }
}
/////////////////////////// triangle ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// update //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function updateAxis()
{
    if(rotationAxis.value == 1)
    {
        rAxisLabel.innerHTML = "Axis Z"
        axisToRotate = 1;
    }
    else if(rotationAxis.value == 2)
    {
        rAxisLabel.innerHTML = "Axis Y";
        axisToRotate = 2;
    }
}

function updateAnimSpeed()
{
    aSpeedLabel.innerHTML = animSpeed.value;
    animSpeedValue = animSpeed.value;
}

function updateDivision()                                       
{
    subLabel.innerHTML = subDivision.value;
    subDivisionCount = subDivision.value;
    colors = [];
    points = [];

}



// update //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

////transformation///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function translation(Tx, Ty, Tz)
{
    var translationValue = mat4();
    translationValue = [
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0,  Tx,
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0,  Ty,
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0,  Tz,
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 
    ];
    var translation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'translation');
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(translation, false , translationValue );
}

function initScale(Sx, Sy, Sz)
{
    var scaleMat = mat4();
    scaleMat = [
        Sx, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0,
        0.0, Sy, 0.0,  0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, Sz,  0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 
    ];

    var initScale = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'initScale');
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(initScale, false, scaleMat);
}

function scaling(Sx, Sy, Sz)
{
    var scaleMat = mat4();
    scaleMat = [
        Sx, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0,
        0.0, Sy, 0.0,  0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, Sz,  0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 
    ];

    var scaling = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'scaling');
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(scaling, false, scaleMat);
}

function rotationX(theta)
{
    var rotationMat = mat4();
    rotationMat = [
        1, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0,
        0.0, Math.cos(theta), -Math.sin(theta) ,  0.0,
        0.0, Math.sin(theta) , Math.cos(theta) ,  0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 
    ];

    var rotateX = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'rotationX')
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(rotateX, false, rotationMat);
}

function rotationY(theta)
{
    var rotationMat = mat4();
    rotationMat = [
        Math.cos(theta), 0.0, Math.sin(theta),  0.0,
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0 ,  0.0,
        -Math.sin(theta), 0.0 , Math.cos(theta) ,  0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 
    ];

    var rotateY = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'rotationY')
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(rotateY, false, rotationMat);
}

function rotationZ(theta)
{
    var rotationMat = mat4();
    rotationMat = [
        Math.cos(theta), -Math.sin(theta), 0.0,  0.0,
        Math.sin(theta), Math.cos(theta), 0.0 ,  0.0,
        0.0, 0.0 , 1.0,  0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 
    ];

    var rotateZ = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'rotationZ')
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(rotateZ, false, rotationMat);
}

////transformation///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: Maybe someone will take find the time to help but the code is doing some unusual things. This won't solve your animation issue but I'd suggest you go read [this article](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrices.html), the 3 that proceed it and the 3 that follow it. You really only need 1 or 2 matrix uniforms in your shader. The rest would usually be matrix math you do in JavaScript.

Comment: @gman hello gman I studied your material, thanks for the website! Its a good resource for learning webgl. I actually fix the bug by remove ' else if ' in the scaletion function and everything works fine , but I dont know why it works. Btw I saw your comment just I was too busy for assignment submission today. I am studying in Universiti Sains Malaysia, not sure if you heard it before haha.

Comment: the problem lies in the    else if (scaleFactor<=1)   of function scaletion   //1 , if I put any value smaller than 1 it works, any value >= 1 it works strange, and I have no idea ~